# Escape Comma from CSV in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm creating a CSV download in my Ruby application which has some Dollar amount fields. These fields has data in cyrrency format like $35,456 and when such data comes in CSV it get seperated into two fiedls , data after comma moved to next column in CSV.

Here is my code to render CSV

```
Sell Date, Sell Amount
- @rows.each do |row|
  = "#{row[0]},#{number_to_currency(row[1], :precision => 2)}"
```

Here is the action used to return CSV

```
def fifolog
  @rows = Report.fifolog()
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { render csv: {:rows =>@rows }}
end
end
```

Is there any escape character i can use to escape "," in ruby

thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Use Ruby's built-in `to_csv` method.

*If you haven't already done so, you'll need to `require 'csv'`.*

```ruby
Sell Date, Sell Amount
- @rows.each do |row|
  = [ row[0], number_to_currency(row[1], :precision => 2) ].to_csv( row_sep: nil ).html_safe
```

`to_csv` is available right on the `Array` and does all the escaping you'd expect it to do.

`row_sep: nil` prevents the `\n` at the end of each row since you're already doing that with `each`. Try it without that and you'll see that you get an extra blank line. If you were just generating a single CSV string then you'd need to keep the `\n` to separate the rows.

`html_safe` prevents the `&quot;` characters from showing up in your CSV file.

That should do it!

JP

Comment: It's worth noting you need to `require 'csv'` before these methods are available.

Answer (score 6):

Use double quotes around values that have a comma:

```
"$35,456"
```

**Edit**:
Using FasterCSV, change the following lines:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { render csv: {:rows =>@rows }}
```

to

```
csv_data = FasterCSV.generate do |csv| 
    csv << ["Sell Date", "Sell Amount"] 

    @rows.each do |row| 
      csv << [row[0],number_to_currency(row[1], :precision => 2)] 
    end 
  end 

  send_data csv_data, 
            :type => 'text/csv', 
            :disposition => "attachment; filename=file.csv"
```

Comment: i tried and it dispaley &quote; in Excel, but this may be wrong syntax, i used this = "\"#{row[0]}\",\"#{number_to_currency(row[1], :precision => 2)}\"..

Comment: That is the correct syntax. I tried it and it displays properly in Open Office. Try opening the raw CSV file in Notepad or vi and see if it actually contains the double quotes.

Comment: If the CSV is coming from a Rails app, then you'll need to set the content-type: `send_data csv_data, :type => "text/plain", :filename=>"file.csv", :disposition => 'attachment'`

Comment: i open it in Notepad and Textpad and its has &quot, i m using Ubuntu and when opened MS Excel , gives same result

Comment: Another option for handling CSV and escaping is FasterCSV (http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: Trevor, i edited my question, added Action used, please check and suggest where i need to add various attributes for CSV, thanks